# Does anybody know how to get a custom woocommerce orders.php on a self created page running?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, error-handling, shortcode

1. I made a custom woocommerce orders page template (only html+css changed; php left original) and saved it to child-theme/woocommerce/orders.php.
2. I loaded the template file inside of "fantasyname.php" inside of a plugin:

   ```
    public function user_settings_page_content() {


    get_template_part( 'woocommerce/myaccount/orders' ); }
   ```

**This is the result:**
[image: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4tevgpS3XB3i2UveSq8]

**I already tried:**

```
    public function user_settings_page_content() {


    get_template_part( 'woocommerce/myaccount/orders' );
    //original shortcode
    do_shortcode ( '[woocommerce_my_account]' );

    //custom shortcode
    do_shortcode ( '[my_orders]' );
    
    $var = do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_my_account]' );
    echo $var; }
```

..but the same error occurs.
Notice: Undefined variable: has_orders in .../hello-theme-child-master/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php on lines 22, 24 and 122.

I can ensure, that there are orders which were made with this account in the last days.

**Summary:**
My custom orders.php template file works, if the url is .../my-account/orders.
If I call the template on another page -> error: undefined variable $has_orders.
All other methods (do_shortcode or using the original orders.php) show the same error.
Only the deprecated file (woocommerce/my-orders template) works without this error (it doesn't make use of has_orders).

Comment: why don't you just override the template with the child theme? you can place the orders.php inside 'themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php'

Comment: Hello, I already did that, but my plugin can do more than just overriding a template.
So I searched for a solution to insert my custom templates into my own plugin.
Now I am free to customize everything and even integrate it into buddypress pages and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this:

```
function csp_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    $basename = basename( $template );
    //orders-template
    if( $basename == 'my-orders.php' ) {
        $template = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'templates/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php';
    }
    //address-template
    elseif( $basename == 'my-address.php' ) {
        $template = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path ( __FILE__ ) ) . 'templates/woocommerce/myaccount/my-address.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'csp_locate_template', 10, 3 );
```

I tried so many snippets and solutions, this is the only one which worked for me 100% reliable.